# Determine using only the definition if it is a Cauchy sequence

Tags: analysis, cauchy-sequences

Determine using only the definition if it is a Cauchy sequence 
$(2n^2+1)/n^2$

Where did I go wrong?

This is what I have so far:

$$\frac{2m^2+1}{m^2}-\frac{2n^2+1}{n^2}=
\frac{n^2(2m^2+1)}{m^2n^2}-\frac{(2n^2+1)m^2}{m^2n^2}=
\frac{n^2-m^2}{m^2 n^2}$$

$$|x_m-x_n|=\frac{|n^2-m^2|}{|m^2n^2|}≤ \frac{m^2}{m^2n^2}<\frac{1}{n^2}≤\frac{ 1}{N^2}<ε $$

Comment: So....Why do you ask where you went wrong?  Why do you think you went wrong anywhere?

Comment: because I know the cauchy formula has the last part except none of it is squared. Being the equation for this one is squared I decided to square the rest as well and I'm not sure if thats what I was suppose to do or if any of this is even right.

Comment: My complaint is you don't explain what you are doing and why.  (What is $N$? and why is $\frac 1{n^2} \le \frac 1{N^2}$? Is there any reason we should assume $n \ge N$?  And what is $\epsilon$ and why is $\frac 1{N^2} < \epsilon$?)  But other than that it seems everything is correct.  That *is* the answer you want because the sequence *is* Cauchy.  So.... why are you asking where you went wrong.

Comment: I assumed it was all that because I was reading the textbook and it said that was the formula for Cauchy sequences. I was asking where I went wrong because I wasn't  sure of my answer and if I was missing something.

Comment: Just because you are unsure of your answer doesn't mean your answer is wrong.  It's very weird to ask "Where did I go wrong" when you *DIDN'T* go wrong anywhere?  A better question is "Is this correct?"

Answer (score 0):

A sequence is cauchy if for any $\epsilon > 0$ then is an $N$ so that for any $n,m \ge N$ then $|x_n -x_m| < \epsilon$.

Here for any $n,m$ we have $|x_n - x_m|< \frac 1{n^2}$ so for *any* $N$ if $n,m \ge N$ we will have $|x_n - x_m| < \frac 1{N^2}$.

Now given any $\epsilon$ if we can find an $N$ so that $\frac 1{N^2} < \epsilon$ that will prove that the sequence is Cauchy.  For any $\epsilon > 0$ *can* we find an $N$ so that $\frac 1{N^2} < \epsilon$?

Well... yes...  $\frac  1{N^2} < \epsilon \iff 0< \frac 1{\epsilon} < N^2 \iff \sqrt{\frac 1{\epsilon}} < |N|$.

So for any $\epsilon > 0$ if we let $N > \sqrt{\frac 1{\epsilon}}$ then for any $n,m \ge N$ we have $|x_n - x_n| < \frac 1{N^2} < \epsilon$.  So it's Cauchy.